# Custom rewrite rule, url returning 404

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a custom URL like this:

```
website.com/show/?id=9999&n=page-name
```

and I'm trying to come up with a `mod_rewrite` rule to convert to

```
website.com/show/9999/page-name/
```

`/show/` is a page name.

Here's the rules I'm using in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^show/(.*)$ /show/?id=$1 [R=301,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is working, it rewrites

```
 website.com/show/?id=9999`
```

to

```
website.com/show/9999/
```

Then I modified the rule for the second query string:

```
RewriteRule ^show/(.*)/(.*)$ /show/?id=$1&n=$2 [R=301,NC,QSA]
```

But `website.com/show/9999/page-name/` returns a 404 error.
It works if I go to: `website.com/show/9999/?n=page-name`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First if all, you don't have to change the rule in the htaccess by yourself. 

This is a general "problem" of WordPress and mostly can be solved by quickedit the posts, change nothing and save.

Comment: I don't think you understand, these are non-WordPress pages.

Comment: please post your solution as a proper answer ;) as for the last part left, it probably best done in an htaccess redirect rule (best here means faster). The other option is to detect those $-GET parameters and redirect at the PHP side

Comment: I think the above issues can be done by changing permalinks of wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out... almost. I needed to use WordPress' own rewrite engine to define the rewrite rules so it recognizes what I'm doing.

So I added this to my WordPress theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'init_custom_rewrite' );

function init_custom_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule(        
        '^show/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',        
        'index.php?page_id=2382&id=$matches[1]&n=$matches[2]',        
        'top' );
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars', 10, 1);

function my_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'id';
    $vars[] = 'n';
    return $vars;
}
```

The URL `website.com/show/9999/page-name` works correctly.

Now I need to redirect the old query string URL: `website.com/show/?id=9999&n=page-name` to the new SEO friendly url: `website.com/show/9999/page-name`

I do that with some rewrite rules in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^/]*)&n=([^/]*)$ 
RewriteRule ^showtest/?$ /showtest\/%1\/%2\/? [R=301,L]
```